# Java Derby Embedded Database won't let me drop last user created table

Tags: java, sql, derby

I have an application where the user can create and delete `tables` in a `Derby Database`.  I'm currently able to add as many as I want, delete as many as I want, except for the 'last' one.

For example, lets say I create the following `tables`:  (the user creates a `table` by entering the name for, nothing else, no `SQL Query` is entered by the user)

Tables:
A, B, C.

I have these tables displayed in a `JTable`, and the user can select as many as they want to 'delete' by highlighting the rows.
So if highlight rows A and B, hit the delete `JButton`, the application deletes or `DROP`s them with no issue.  But if I then try to delete row C, it doesn't do anything.

Same issue occurs if I select all of the rows.

This is the code that's doing the work:

```
public final void removeDBTable(String tableName){
        try{
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("DROP TABLE ").append(tableName);           
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(sb.toString());
            stmt.close();
        }catch (SQLException ex){
            if(ex.getErrorCode() != 30000){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

If anyone wants an SSCCE I can put one together, but currently don't have one ready.

---

#### TL;DR:

Can not delete/`DROP` last `table` in my database.

Comment: Is `removeDBTable` being executed for all the tables selected in your UI? Have you used a debugger to confirm the value of `tableName` inside the method?

Comment: @Turophile Sorry, I should've included more information.  But sometimes too much doesn't help either.

Comment: @Turophile And yes, I have a loop that runs through each selected row.  I know this loop is working because I've had it print out each table name at the same time.  Every attempt at deleting the last table, it does show the correct table name too.

Comment: @Turophile Figured out my issue, never closed the ResultSet I created when making the database.  Fixed it now.  You're help was appriciated!